# createAssetAsync doesn't work on Android 10

Tags: react-native, expo, media-library

MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri) on Android 10 always returns an error as `Error: Unable to copy file into external storage.`. This happens only on Android 10 device. I can use it without any problem on Android 9. Any idea to how to solve this?

Comment: Same problem in android 11.

Comment: Did you find any thing?